# What is the function of "ingenti" in Apocolocyntosis 12, 3?

Tags: classical-latin

What is the function of "ingenti" in Apocolocyntosis 12, 3?

> Claudius, ut vidit funus suum, intellexit se mortuum esse, Ingenti enim megaloi xorikoi nenia cantabatur (anapaestis).

My understanding is Harvard Prof. G. Schmeling's translation: "For with a great song and dance a dirge was being sung." That would make "nenia" the nom. sing. subject of "cantabatur". But ingenti is probably abl. so.....

Comment: What's your current understanding of this sentence? That will help us in answering.

Comment: My understanding is Harvard Prof. G. Schmeling's translation: "For with a great song and dance a dirge was being sung." That would make "nenia" the nom. sing. subject of "cantabatur". But ingenti is probably abl. so.....

Comment: I've edited that information into the question. If my edits don't properly reflect your intent, feel free to re-edit to correct that.

Comment: Thank you, Draconis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the Loeb text:

> Ingenti enim μεγάλωι χορικῶι nenia cantabatur.

Note that the Greek words end in ωι, which is a dative singular ending in Greek. Since the Greek dative can be used in similar ways to the Latin ablative, I suppose you could also consider these words to be in the "ablative"; Greek doesn't have that case, but you have to make compromises when you're mixing forms between languages like this.

*Ingenti* then goes with these: the song and dance is so great it's not just μεγάλωι, it's also *ingenti*. *Nenia* is, as you surmise, nominative singular: the subject of *cantabatur*.